# How can I transform an html button link to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is Alex, a python newbie which needs a little bit of help with an automation task.

For a monthly report, I would need to be able to extract some values monthly (i.e. 119.032 - " Kredite für Wohnbau" Sep. 20) from the following table (https://www.oenb.at/isaweb/report.do?lang=DE&report=1.5.13).

On the upper left side there is an html button (Go) to export the data either in excel or csv.

My goal would be to access the download file url and directly import it with pandas read_csv.

I have tried the following without success:

[Screenshot of chrome navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsrPg.png)

1). pd.read_html(r'https://www.oenb.at/isaweb/reportExcelHtml.do?report=1.5.13&sort=ASC&dynValue=0&lang=DE&linesPerPage=allen&timeSeries=All&page=1')

Which results in a rather chaotic output.

2). df = pd.read_csv('https://www.oenb.at/isaweb/reportExcelHtml.do?report=1.5.13&sort=ASC&dynValue=0&lang=DE&linesPerPage=allen&timeSeries=All&page=1', error_bad_lines=False)

Which instead of the values shows only the following:

[Read_CSV outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShWv1.png)

I would be extremely grateful for any advice on how to get this working.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by sending POST request and then creating DataFrame from content of request using pandas. Make sure you have properly decoded string containing data.

```
data = requests.post('https://www.oenb.at/isaweb/reportExcelHtml.do;jsessionid=F96C45B1B1CA4A34D676CEDF8A21FE32?report=1.5.13&sort=ASC&dynValue=0&lang=DE&linesPerPage=allen&timeSeries=All&page=1&export=CSV&buttonExport=Go')
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data.content.decode('iso-8859-1')), sep=';')
```

Comment: This is pretty cool!  would add that need to remember to `import requests` and `from io import StringIO` for this to run.

Comment: Thank you very much Krzysztof and yulGM! Extremely useful, everything worked :)